# C# custom duplicate check skipping one element

Tags: c#

I have been doing one task :) And I need to create a duplicate checker, to check, which element is repeating, and which right index is the highest - return it. I have been struggling with one test case.

Here is the code:

```cs
    public struct DataHolder
    {
        public int number, idx1, idx2;
    }
    public int FirstDuplicateValue(int[] array)
    {
        if (array == null || array.Length == 0 || array.Length == 1) return -1;

        List<DataHolder> holder = new();

        for(int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            for(int j = i + 1; j < array.Length - 1; j++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Array i: {array[i]} Array j: {array[j]}");
                if (array[i] == array[j])
                {
                    var matches = holder.Where(x => x.number == array[i]).ToList();
                    if(matches.Count == 0)
                        holder.Add(new DataHolder()
                        {
                            number = array[i],
                            idx1 = i,
                            idx2 = j
                        });
                }
            }
        }
        if (holder.Count == 0) return array[0];
        else
        {
            holder.Sort((x, y) => x.idx2 - y.idx2);
            return holder[0].number;
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] testValues = { 2, 1, 5, 3, 3, 2, 4 };
        int result = new Program().FirstDuplicateValue(testValues);
        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
```

It works fine, with the test case I wrote in the code. But with `{ 2,1,1 }` for example, it does not work. Seems to me, like it is skipping last element somehow

Comment: `j < array.Length - 1`?

Comment: @DavidL Yes :) Because if not, it would go above the length of an array

Comment: Are you looking for the *rightmost* duplicate? E.g. for `1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 2, 5` it should be `2`: both `2` and `3` are duplicated, but the last `2` appears after the last `3`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko For the duplicate that last(right) element is closest to the beginning of an array. So in this case it would be 3(Because last 3 is index 5. But last 2 index is 7)

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood you right, you want to find the very *first* duplicate, i.e. to check as few items of the array as possible:

```
  2, 1, 5, 3, 3, 2, 4 ...
              ^
              3 is duplicate to return, 
                may be 2, 1, 5 are duplicates as well (2 is duplicate)
                but we don't want to scan any more and 
                return as early as possible
```

If it's you task, you can solve it with `HashSet<int>`: we add items of the array to `HashSet<int>` and whenever we can't do it we have a duplicate.

```
    public static int FirstDuplicateValue(int[] array) {
      if (array is null || array.Length <= 1)
        return -1;

      var unique = new HashSet<int>();

      foreach (var item in array) 
        if (!unique.Add(item))
          return item;

      return -1;   
    }
```

This solution is faster (`O(n)` vs. `O(n**3)` in the worst case) but wants `O(n)` additional memory.